# Install Gitlab with disabled sign up

Tags: git, docker, ansible, gitlab

I am building an automatic deployment platform containing a Gitlab instance.
This Gitlab instance is inside a docker and it is deployed through Ansible.

I would like to customize Gitlab settings before deploying it but after some readings of the documentation, I cannot find how to disable sign up without using the Administration HMI.

- Some people says "*Modify /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb to add a parameter to disable signup*" : I don't have this file on my filesystem & it doesn't work on my machine.
- I also tried to modify the file gitlab.yml, and my setting is removed after I restart my docker. And it doesn't work.
- I could use the API, but I need the admin token, only accessible through its HMI (sic).
- I could alter the database of my gitlab instance... But what a complex operation for this simple setting.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Is this your own container? Is it a container from dockerhub?

Comment: It is my own container. The image is built from a dockerfile similar to https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab/blob/bf5a5766ae3d65d9594df46b55e68a5dfff5b659/Dockerfile. I use Gitlab 8.7.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This docker container is being configured via enviroment variables. What you need to do is to set this variable or create a env-file with your parameters (recommended).

The parameter you are looking for is `GITLAB_SIGNUP_ENABLED=false`

You do this either with `docker run <other parameter> -e GITLAB_SIGNUP_ENABLED=false` or with `--env-file <path-to-enviroment-vars>`.

All configuration switches are [here](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab#available-configuration-parameters).